# WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console Application Servers status not sync

Tags: java, console, websphere

Good day,

The version of Integrated Solutions Console, 8.5.5.3

Currently, I have a WAS server where I can interact to it through WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console UI.

My application server running without using cluster, base on my understanding, I believe that I have no node, and I believe I do not have deployment manager as well. (I am not familiar how is the WAS server and console working. Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Few days ago, I found that I was unable to stop/start my Application Servers through console UI. I tried to find the root cause from the server log file, JVM logs, but nothing error there. The error message just display in console UI, for example, as follow:
[image]

and [image]

Since there is no log error at time occurrence. I tried go through the log from begining, I stop the application server through command, and start it through command as well.

I delete those temporary files inside :

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Profiles/DefaultAppSrvAA01/wstemp
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Profiles/DefaultAppSrvAA01/temp
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Profiles/DefaultAdminAgent01/wstemp
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Profiles/DefaultAdminAgent01/temp
```

After delete those temporary file, I tried to start the server application again, sadly, the same error still exists.

The log is as follow:

```
[3/28/17 10:44:42:566 CST] 00000001 ObjectGridCat I   CWOBJ0072I: The WebSphere eXtreme Scale command runtime environment is using the SYSTEM Subject RunAs type.
[3/28/17 10:44:42:765 CST] 00000001 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /logs/ffdc/SITSMEVNSCAPP02_7d1b8844_17.03.28_10.44.42.7613278459503260396676.txt com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ConfigUtility.getCatalogServicesWCCM 804
[3/28/17 10:44:42:767 CST] 00000001 ConfigUtility E   An exception occurred while initializing the getCatalogServicesWCCM: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: Unable to get Server MBean
    at com.ibm.ws.management.cmdframework.impl.AgentProxyAdminClient.getServerMBean(AgentProxyAdminClient.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.cmdframework.impl.CommandUtility.getRemoteCmdMgrMbean(CommandUtility.java:72)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.cmdframework.impl.ClientCommandMgr.initCommandMetadata(ClientCommandMgr.java:317)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.cmdframework.impl.ClientCommandMgr.createCommand(ClientCommandMgr.java:295)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ConfigUtility.getCatalogServicesWCCM(ConfigUtility.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.initialize(ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initWsComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1192)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1099)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponents(ContainerHelper.java:901)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:750)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.initialize(ServerImpl.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:224)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:697)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:398)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:161)

[3/28/17 10:44:42:861 CST] 00000001 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /logs/ffdc/SITSMEVNSCAPP02_7d1b8844_17.03.28_10.44.42.7896070365472281099478.txt com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.getZone 1170
[3/28/17 10:44:42:898 CST] 00000001 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /logs/ffdc/SITSMEVNSCAPP02_7d1b8844_17.03.28_10.44.42.8632205815468637941074.txt com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.getZone 1181
[3/28/17 10:44:42:903 CST] 00000001 RuntimeInfo   I   CWOBJ0903I: The internal version of WebSphere eXtreme Scale is v7.0.3 (8.6.0.3) [cf31329.18064852].
```

From this above log, we can see there is still another 3 FFDC log:

First FFDC error log is same as the SystemOut.log, so I will not upload here.

Second FFDC log and third FFDC log are almost the same:

```
[3/28/17 10:44:42:789 CST]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.getZone ProbeId
:1170 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl@9d3500c1
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException: ADMN1211E: Unable to open connector to admin agent while processing method queryConfigObjects for interface com.ibm.websphere.manageme
nt.configservice.ConfigService
        at com.ibm.wsspi.management.collaborator.AgentProxyCollaborator.mapAndThrowException(AgentProxyCollaborator.java:499)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.management.collaborator.AgentProxyCollaborator.invoke(AgentProxyCollaborator.java:224)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.queryConfigObjects(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceServerProxy$11.run(ConfigServiceServerProxy.java:454)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:327)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:125)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceServerProxy.queryConfigObjects(ConfigServiceServerProxy.java:444)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.nodegroup.NodeGroupHelper.getNodeGroups(NodeGroupHelper.java:1801)
        at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.getZone(ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.java:901)
        at com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.initialize(ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl.java:529)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initWsComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1192)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1099)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponents(ContainerHelper.java:901)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:750)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.initialize(ServerImpl.java:353)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:293)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:224)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:697)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:398)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:161)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException
        at com.ibm.ws.management.RoutingTable.getParent(RoutingTable.java:230)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.management.collaborator.AgentProxyCollaborator.initialize(AgentProxyCollaborator.java:296)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.management.collaborator.AgentProxyCollaborator.invoke(AgentProxyCollaborator.java:211)
        ... 44 more

Reporter BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.objectgrid.integration.ObjectGridCatalogComponentImpl@9d3500c1
com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl::tc BEGIN:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@a6599642
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivLevel:10
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivName:com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDebugEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEventEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEntryEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDetailEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivConfigEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivInfoEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivServiceEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivWarningEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivErrorEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivFatalEnabled:true
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::defaultMessageFile:com.ibm.ejs.resources.seriousMessages
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::EXTENSION_NAME_DPID:DiagnosticProvider
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDumpEnabled:false
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivResourceBundleName:com.ibm.ws.runtime.runtime
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivLogger:null
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDiagnosticProviderID:null
 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::anyTracingEnabled:null
 END:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@a6599642
```

Kindly advise on what problem I am facing. I am stuck inside this problem, hopefully someone can point me my mistake.

Comment: The ffdc shows that while one jvm was trying to establish communication with another using the ipc connector, it ran into an expired certificate.  I'm not sure exactly how to fix that. Once the jvm's can "talk" again you should be able to start/stop things from the UI.  Meanwhile you can probably do it from the command line.

Comment: The SSL Keystores to check are 'CellDefaultKeyStore' and 'NodeDefaultKeyStore'. Under each one, check the 'Personal certificates' section. From the error message, it appears that one of those certificates expired on Feb 05. If it is a self-signed certificate, you can renew it. If it is a CA-signed certificate, you'll need to generate the new CSR and get it signed.

Comment: Hi, I already edit my question, now the cert issue no more exist. So i believe its not cause by cert issue.